# D3 Topojson Merge - Retrieve Multipolygon Coordinates and Save to JSON

Tags: d3.js, topojson

**Update**

I have made some progress and updated my question in light of my new understanding of topojson's functions.

To achieve my previous goal I used a method similar to [this example](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/5416405). Namely, I hard-coded the FIPS id's of the counties I wished to merge into a `set` then created a `FeatureCollection` to use for creating my paths. Here is one example for northern Texas:

```
var set1 = d3.set([
  48111, 48421, 48195, 48357, 48295, 48205, 48341, 48233, 48393, 48211,
  48359, 48375, 48065, 48179, 48483, 48485, 48077, 48337, 48237, 48009,
  48503, 48023, 48269, 48125, 48107, 48303, 48219, 48079, 48501, 48445,
  48305, 48169,
  48117, 48381, 48011, 48129, 48087, 48369, 48069, 48437, 48045, 48191,
  48075, 48017, 48279, 48189, 48153, 48345, 48101, 48155, 48197, 48487
]);

var region1 = {type: "FeatureCollection", features: counties.filter(function(d) {return set1.has(d.id); })};

countiesG.append("path")
    .datum(region1)
    .attr("class", "region")
    .attr("d", path);

countiesG.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) {return set1.has(d.id); })))
    .attr("class", "region-boundary")
    .attr("d", path);

var set2 = d3.set([
      17035, 17032, 17038, 17083, 17022, 17062
    ]);

var region2 = {type: "FeatureCollection", features: counties.filter(function(d) {return set2.has(d.id); })};

countiesG.append("path")
    .datum(region2)
    .attr("class", "region")
    .attr("d", path);

countiesG.append("path")
    .datum(topojson.merge(us, us.objects.counties.geometries.filter(function(d) {return set2.has(d.id); })))
    .attr("class", "region-boundary")
    .attr("d", path);
```

I will just provide two region's code above for reference. In reality, I repeated this process many times to create all of my desired merged conglomerate regions. Hard-coding all of this data was arduous and makes my code less readable. My hope is that the hard work is behind me, and I can somehow use these new merged multi-polygon regions in the future.

**My question is:** Now that I have hard-coded every region, can topojson somehow save the coordinates of these new merged multipolygons into the original us.json file or even a new json file? That way when I parse the json's coordinates it will have all of my custom merged regions -- which would allow me to delete all my hard-coded regions. I'm open to other approaches as well, as long as I can achieve my goal of exporting the merged multipolygon boundary coordinates.

Comment: Could you please add an image of the result you want to see ? What you want to achieve is very unclear at the moment (at least to me).

Comment: Ok, sorry for the confusion. Made a few edits to the post; hope this clears things up for everyone.

Comment: Do you know `topojson.merge`? https://github.com/topojson/topojson-client/blob/master/README.md#merge